# Scoped navigation service in Prism UWP

Tags: frame, prism, uwp, navigationservice, splitview

I am using Prism 6 for UWP and Unity.

Scenario:
I have a login page, and some other selection pages before I navigate to a Menu page that hosts a SplitView control. I want the navigation from this point to only target the content area of the SplitView control, but because my INavigationService was created in the context of the initial Frame I cannot do this.

I have seen the SplitView example but that basically sets the SplitView UI as the top Window.Current.Content right off the bat.  This is why I am seeing the current behavior. I cannot simply take the initial Frame and set is to the SplitView Content area.

What is a good way to have my navigation now target the SplitView Content area?
- Recreating a navigation service? Don't know how I would inject this in the correct pages.